# Laravel: How to add to each object in collection with condition

Tags: laravel, collections

I want to return the editing rights of the active user in the laravel collection. So each object in the collection should have the additional value 'edit' = 0 or 1, depending on if the item's "AuthorID" matches the current users ID.

So I believe I need a combination of **each()**, **if()** and probably **put()/push()**?

```
    $collection = $collection->each(function($item, $key) {

                if ($item->AuthorID == Auth::user()->id) {
                    
                    // may edit item
                    $item->push('edit',1);

                }else{
                
                   // not allowed to edit item
                    $item->push('edit',0);
                }  
});
```

So far I didn't succeed, the result was that instead of the collection I now only have the value "1". How can I solve this?

Comment: why are you calling `push` on a model instance? that updates it in the database and its relationships, it does not set any values and it takes no arguments ... just set an attribute on the model    `$item->edit = ...` (assuming you will not try to save this model instance later)

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you, I changed it to $item->edit = [..] and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

As @lagbox stated in the comments, the right thing to do is:

```
$collection = $collection->each(function($item, $key) {

            if ($item->AuthorID == Auth::user()->id) {
                
                // may edit item
                $item->edit = 1;

            }else{
            
               // not allowed to edit item
                $item->edit = 0;
            }
```

});